# severe regex hangtime python

Tags: python, regex

I have a small (40mb) server log, linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svq64i27b75l4fu/access_log.txt)

I have a regular expression which I'm using to parse through the code that takes an INCREDIBLY (5+ minute) time to get through.  I'm relatively new to regex, so I'm not sure why this would take so long for such a small file

here's the expression:

```
valid=re.findall(r'(\d+/[a-zA-Z]+/\d+).*?(GET|POST)\s+(http://|https//)([a-zA-Z]+.+?)\.[^/].*?\.([a-zA-Z]+)(/|\s|:).*?\s200\s', line)
```

things really started to chug when I added the "200" at the end of the line

and here's the entire code:

```
    import re
#todo
#specify toplevel domain lookback
######

fhandle=open("access_log.txt", "rU")
access_log=fhandle.readlines()

validfile=open("valid3.txt", "w")
invalidfile=open("invalid3.txt", "w")


valid_dict=dict()
invalid_list=list()
valid_list=list()


#part 1
#read file. apply regex and append into internal data structure (a 2d dictionary)
for line in access_log:
    valid=re.findall(r'(\d+/[a-zA-Z]+/\d+).*?(GET|POST)\s+(http://|https//)([a-zA-Z]+.+?)\.[^/].*?\.([a-zA-Z]+)(/|\s|:).*?\s200\s', line)
    #valid=re.findall(r'(\d+/[a-zA-Z]+/\d+).*?(GET|POST)\s+(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z]+.+?)\.[^/].*?\.([a-zA-Z]+)(/|\s|:).*?\s+200\s', line)
    if valid:
        date=valid[0][0]
        domain=valid[0][4].lower()
        valid_list.append(line)


        #writes results into 2d dcitonary (dictionary of dictonaries)
        if date not in valid_dict:
            valid_dict[date]={}
        else:
            if domain in valid_dict[date]:
                valid_dict[date][domain]+=1
            else:
                valid_dict[date][domain]=1
    #writes remainder files into invalid file log
    else:
        invalid_list.append(line)



#step 2
#format output file for tsv
#ordered chronologically, with Key:Value pairs orgainzed alphabeticallv by key (Domain Name)
date_workspace=''
domain_workspace=''

for date in sorted(valid_dict.iterkeys()):
    date_workspace+=date + "\t"

    for domain_name in sorted(valid_dict[date].iterkeys()):
        domain_workspace+="%s:%s\t" % (domain_name, valid_dict[date][domain_name])

    date_workspace+=domain_workspace
    date_workspace+="\n"    
    domain_workspace=''

# Step 3
# write output
validfile.write(date_workspace)
for line in invalid_list:
    invalidfile.write(line) 



fhandle.close()
validfile.close()
invalidfile.close()
```

Comment: This is usually due to nested `+`/`*` quantifiers somewhere causing [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @user2357112: There is no nested quantifiers in his pattern.

Comment: Didn't find any nested quantifiers after examining the regex. The many instances of `.*?` could cause a similar effect, though. It's limited to polynomial-time problems instead of exponential, but there are still a ton of ways to match the various `.*?` patterns that the regex engine will need to go through individually if none of them make the overall match work.

Comment: Actually, I'm probably looking at the wrong things for the slowdown. It might just be that 202,146 lines is a lot of data, or it might be that Python's string concatenation optimization isn't triggering and the code that builds `date_workspace` is getting quadratic runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep the domain name extension, you can change the regex part of your code like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^[^[]+\[(\d+/[a-zA-Z]+/\d+)[^]]+] "(?:GET|POST) https?://[a-zA-Z]+[^?/\s]*\.([a-zA-Z]+)[?/ :][^"]*" 200 ')

for line in access_log:
    valid=pattern.search(line)

    if valid:
        date=valid.group(1)
        domain=valid.group(2).lower()
        valid_list.append(line)
```

Improvements: 5min -> 2s

Since you read the file line by line there is only one possible match in a line, it is better to use `re.search` that returns the first match instead of `re.findall`.

The pattern is used once per line, this is why I have choosen to compile the pattern before the loop.

The pattern is now anchored with the *start of the string* anchor `^` and the begining of the line is now described with `[^[]+\[` (all that is not a `[` one or more times followed by a `[`). This improvement is very important since it avoids the regex engine to try the start of the pattern at each character of the line.

All `.*?` are slow for two reasons (at least):

- a lazy quantifier must test if the following subpattern matches for each character.
- if the pattern fails later, since `.*?` can match all characters, the regex engine doesn't have the smallest reason to stop its backtracking. In other words, the good way is to be as explicit as possible.

To do that you must replace all `.*?` with a negative character class and a greedy quantifier.

All uneeded capturing groups have been replaced with a non capturing group `(?:...)`.

Some other trivial changes have been made like `(http://|https://) => https?://` or `(/|\s|:) => [?/ :]`. All `\s+` have been replaced with a space.

As an aside comment, I am sure that there is a lot of log parser/analyser for python that can help you. Note too that your log file uses a csv format.

Comment: Thank you for this, I appreciate the example regex as well.  As I work with regex, I find that I care very little about most of the string, and I simply want the engine to examine the next item.  I've started mentally equating .*? with telling the engine "just keep moving until you hit my next specific group".  Is there a more thoughtful way to solve this?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, like I explained in the post, the way is to describe the content before the next group, for example with a character class that match the content but doesn't contain the first character of the group. example with a directory in a path: `/.+?/` => `/[^/]+/`

Comment: I see, that's a different way of thinking-appreciate the clarification!